# How to sync PostgreSQL data and ReactNative mobile app data?

Tags: android, ios, postgresql, react-native

I am working on a web application written in Django and using PostgreSQL as the database backend. I'd like to spin up a ReactNative mobile app so that users can operate the app offline. I am concerned about managing database conflicts where a user takes one action offline on the mobile app, takes a conflicting action in the web app, and then the two actions need to be synced, conflicts managed, and merged.

I understand that you don't want ReactNative to connect directly to your PostgreSQL DB from ReactNative as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995930/react-native-connect-to-postgresql-database). I also am aware of [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#docsNav) in ReactNative. I am unaware of how to best integrate the two. I have seen several questions on syncing web app data with mobile data (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810300/background-data-sync-for-mobile-apps)) but **I am looking specifically for a PostgreSQL and ReactNative solution**. I see a lot of [results](https://github.com/pervasync/react-native-sync) for DB solutions in ReactNative, but I am not looking for the new hotness or a pet project that will eventually not be maintained. I've also heard of [RealmDB](https://realm.io/) which looks great but does not seem to be free. In short, **I am looking for the most reliable, simple, and proven solution for managing data in ReactNative and syncing with PostgreSQL.**

*I am asking now without any ReactNative code because I want to make sure I set up the ReactNative app correctly from the start, rather than having to go back and rewrite all my data storage code.*

To use a very basic example, let's say while on the subway and without WiFi or mobile data, a user changes `task_A` from `incomplete->complete`. The user then jumps on his laptop after arriving at work and changes the state of `task_A` from `incomplete->in_progress`. When the user gets his mobile device on WiFi and syncs the app data there will be a conflict between the mobile data stored using `AsyncStorage` and the data living in PostgresDB.

**What is the best data storage wrapper for `ReactNative` given the web application uses Django and PostgreSQL?**

I've also asked this on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53061/recommended-software-for-syncing-postgresql-data-and-reactnative-mobile-app-data) but it is eerily quiet over there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add `pouchDB` to your ReactNative app instead of `AsyncStorage` and connect it to your Postgres DB using `pouchDB` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953256/how-to-have-complete-offline-functionality-in-a-web-app-with-postgresql-database/19960452#19960452)

> UPDATE: It is worth investigating `Operational Transformations` for
>   future reference:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) on Operational Transformations
- [github.io](https://operational-transformation.github.io/) on Operational Transformations